# How to automate importing certificates on a Windows CE device?

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, import, certificate, windows-ce

I'd like to automate importing cert(s) on a Windows CE device.  Pushing the certs down to the devices is not a problem, but once they are there I cannot determine how to import them without using the UI.

(I'm currently using Avalanche Mobility Center)

Comment: Did you mean Windows CE device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to push certificates onto windows mobile devices is to use Windows Mobile Device Provisioning.

[MSDN Provisioning Mobile Devices Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500581.aspx)

For examples of certificate provisioning, in any of the Windows Mobile SDK directories, there is a SDKTools directory with examples xml files.
e.g. on a standard VS 2008 install with the SmartDeice SDK installed

...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\SDKTools

As the above article points out, there are a number of ways you can provisioning a device. Installer CAB or CPF, an native application using the API or remotely connected device using RAPI or over the air (altho over the air is not really an option unless you are a mobile operator).

[MSDN: CertificateStore Configuration Service Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/bb737346.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the certificate from the command line.  The easiest way to figure out what is happening is to go in to the .cert extension in Windows ME and see what command gets executed when a double click happens.

Comment: What are you talking about?  This is Windows *CE* not *ME*.  His device may or may not have a "command line" and in any case, there's no command line ever executed.

Comment: To be fair the first version of the question before the edit stated ME in both the title and the body