# Specify client certificates in HttpWebRequest in .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, x509certificate

Previously, I was trying to use client certificate on .NET CF 2.0 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885077/specify-client-certificates-in-httpwebrequest-in-net-compact-framework-2-0)) and I ultimately had to give up.  I'm now on .NET CF 3.5 which has support for the `ClientCertificates` property on the `HttpWebRequest` object.  However, I can't figure out how to instantiate the `X509Certificate` or `X509Certificate2` object with a pfx file.  On the full framework, I can simply do something like `new X509Certificate2(filename, password)`.  If I try to create the object with bytes read from a .pfx file, I get an exception saying ".NET CF 3.5 does not support pfx files".  So how do I specify a client certificate with a private key for use with the `ClientCertificates` property?

Answer (score 1):

According to MDSN there are only 2 contructors available/supported by the compact framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.x509certificate2.aspx

The .NET CF supported constructors have a little device icon next to them in the first column.

These are:

```
X509Certificate2(array<Byte>[]()[])
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413.aspx

```
X509Certificate2(IntPtr)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148414.aspx

Comment: Yes, I noticed that.  What I don't understand is how do I specify a client certificate for use with SSL client authentication when compact framework's X509Certificate object does not support a private key?  It is my understanding that the private key is used to authenticate the client to the server so that the server may trust the client.  I can't see any way to do that on the compact framework despite Microsoft having added the ClientCertificates property in 3.5...

Comment: I think the way to do this is to use the X509Store class to access certificates in the local certificate store, then use these certificate - rather than loading one from file.

Comment: Ok, interesting... How would I add a certificate to the store with the associated private key?

Comment: I've not done this personally, but I believe that provision CE devices with certificates (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287316/how-to-automate-importing-certificates-on-a-windows-ce-device) or you can use the CE UI to do this (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900349.aspx for hints)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the provisioning is only available on Windows Mobile.  I need to run on plain old Windows CE.  The cert UI in the control panel could work, but I need to automate this programmatically.  Can you add .pvk files to the store using X509Store?  If not, I need to figure out how to use the appropriate Win32 API to do this...